# Scrollposition as a variable in css?

Tags: css

I'm working on a webpage with very complex non default scroll behaviour. Stuff is suppose to move over the screen based on how much you scroll and stuff like that. I know I can use javascript to add classes on different positions, something like this:

```
wrap.on("scroll", function(e) {

   if (this.scrollTop > 147) {
     wrap.addClass("fix-search");
   } else {
     wrap.removeClass("fix-search");
   }
});
```

But now I need the actual scrollposition as a value in css. I would like to do something like this, this should cause a object to fly up over the screen twice as fast as you are scrolling.

```
.floatingObject {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: calc(var(--scrollPosition)*2);
}
```

Is something like this possible? Can you maybe store the value in the DOM and retrieve it as a css-variable/property etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

In your scrollListener just add something like the following:

`document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--scrollPosition', this.scrollTop);`

In your css `:root {--scrollPosition:0}`

Mind that this has no support in IE so you'll need a fallback everywhere you want to use the variable.

Comment: Also for anyone else, custom varibables are not supported in IE but they are in Edge.

Comment: The 0 as default value makes sure your CSS does not break before your page is even loaded and make it clear a numeric value is expected.
Having `undefined` or `null` does not play nice in CSS `calc`.

Comment: and replace onScroll with an [intersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) that actually triggers often enough, like in this demo: https://css-tricks.com/an-explanation-of-how-the-intersection-observer-watches/#understanding-the-intersectionratio-property